Exclude HTTP 501s from `HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count` CloudWatch metric
I have an AWS Application Load Balancer, and am doing some alerting based on the HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count CloudWatch metric, but it unfortunately triggers for HTTP 501s as well:

HTTP 501: Not implemented
The load balancer received a Transfer-Encoding header with an unsupported value. The supported
values for Transfer-Encoding are chunked and identity. As an alternative, you can use the
Content-Encoding header.

AWS ALB 501s can be easily triggered by clients (curl -i --http1.1 --data "hi" --header "Transfer-Encoding: omg" "https://api.example.com/my_api"), so: is there to be a way to get a CloudWatch metric count for 5XXs that aren't 501s.
I know there are other options (CloudWatch logs and querying, doing a Lambda, paying $$$$$$$ to block via AWS WAF), but I'd just like to see if this is possible to do via CW metrics.
(There IS a pretty clever way to exclude some other 5XXs using Composite Metrics, but unfortunately there is no HTTPCode_ELB_501_Count metric to exclude! Why? WHY!?)

The other, less costly way is to create a custom metric using a Lambda function, which filters logs and creates a custom metric. You can then set up CloudWatch alarms on this metric. Here’s a basic implementation:
Option 1: Create a Custom Metric via Lambda
This Lambda function processes log events, filters out 501 responses, and emits a metric for other 5XX errors:
import boto3
import json

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['logEvents']:
        log_message = json.loads(record['message'])
        status_code = log_message.get('elb_status_code')
        
        if status_code and status_code.startswith('5') and status_code != '501':
            cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
                Namespace='CustomMetrics',
                MetricData=[
                    {
                        'MetricName': 'Filtered_5XX',
                        'Value': 1,
                        'Unit': 'Count'
                    }
                ]
            )

the second best approach might be to update your existing CloudWatch Alarm to trigger the Lambda function only when needed. Here’s how this works:
1.  Set up an alarm on the standard HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count metric.

2.  When the alarm triggers, it invokes the Lambda function.

3.  The Lambda function queries Logs Insights to make sure that the logs doesn't have 501.

4.  If it detects other 5XX errors, the Lambda function can send an alert via SNS or other means.

But, sadly no way to just use the default HTTP metrics
